# How can I add a jar and build a project same as eclipse using command line

Tags: android, command-line, build

I have a project which I import to my eclipse workspace. It has some jar dependency, some of which need special consideration like ordering up them than android.jar and some to make check in some specific place. Now, I have to do all of these work done in command line without using eclipse. I want your help to find it out how it is possible using command line.
I have found a lot of tutorial on command line build and succeeded to implement them on a newly created project which does not have any dependency jar. I did that using ant.
But when I try to do that for my project which have dependency jar like the following picture:
![project properties[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIaKY.jpg)

Here ZETA is a user library build by eclipse where all of my jar is on.

Can anyone now help me to find out how can I do the same procedure without eclipse and also want to know what the check in means in the picture.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a great build system for the Android.  [Here is a link](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted) to a "getting started" section in Google's documentation.

Comment: I don't find any good documentaion or guide here how can I use that for my purpose. Can you give me some more hints?